# Calculation of self-inductance of an arbitrary shape

Tags: electromagnetic-induction, inductance

I have been taught two methods for doing this however I do not understand one of them completely. I will try to explain what I don't understand with a few examples.

---

> Irodov 3.319: A long coaxial cable consists of two thin walled cylinders with radii $a$ and $b$ ($a$ < $b$). The current flows down the surface of inner cylinder and back along the outer cylinder. Find the self-inductance. [image: diagram along with loop]

Now my teacher uses $L = \Phi_B/I$ to calculate self-inductance. He takes the loop drawn in green, finds the magnetic flux passing through it and divides it by the current flowing in the cables. What I don't understand is why this loop only? As far as I know self-inductance is caused due to generation of emf passing through "itself" which opposes the change of current, but how exactly do you define "itself"? How do you know what loop to consider?
Also, if you consider this loop, if I am not wrong the emf generated should be along the loop but how does that affect the current really (in this case)?

---

There was another diagram given by my teacher however in this case I can kind of understand what loop we take. Clearly if we consider the circuit to be the loop itself and apply the definition of $L = \Phi_B/i$, we can get the self-inductance of this shape.

> [image]

---

The other method involved finding the magnetic energy stored inside the shape, $U$ and using the fact that $U = \frac{1}{2}Li^2$ to find the self-inductance ($U$ can be found by taking the volume integral of $u$, energy density). This method makes more sense to me since we find the integral for the whole volume i.e. we have clearly defined what the volume is.

The questions were stated in the first example. Thank you.